# Hosted VB.Net Application with SQL Server Database & Filesharing?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

A company I work for has an application written in VB.net with a SQL Server database storing all information. Works fine no complaints, but we also want to upload/download files within the application, and have the files + SQL Server database on a remote server i.e. working over the internet.

We could just use a VPN but that's not the best method. What would you suggest we use to communicate securely between the application and the remote server for both the database and filesharing?

I was thinking of doing everything over HTTPS, but we would need some kind of agent on the other end to receive requests.

Sorry if this is a noob question, I have no experience with VB.net myself, I usually use PHP + C!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a VPN. It implies just deployment and configuration.

'Going over HTTPS' means you rewrite your application, as the current VB app is expecting T-SQL and SMB endpoints to discuss with.

Comment: VB + SQL can't be done in an object-orientated fashion then so the transport details can be changed without requiring a total rewrite? Problem with VPN's is the system is down if the endpoint fails, HTTPS can be load balanced etc.